# Vaadin play audio mobile device

Tags: audio, vaadin7

I want to play a notification sound for my Vaadin based website on Android and iOS devices.  The notification sound works perfect on desktops.  How do I get it to work on mobile devices.

I am using the "Audio" component, with no controls displayed, and just "play" it when I need it.  It is a very short sound and small file.

Edit 6/1/2017 ( my current implementation ):
First of all, in the constructor for my very simple form:

```
    barcode.setInputPrompt("Barcode");
    barcode.setCaption("Barcode");
    barcode.setMaxLength(22);
    barcode.setNullRepresentation("");
    barcode.setRequired(true);

    submit = new Button("Submit");

    addComponents(barcode, facilityId, submit );

    submit.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_PRIMARY);
    submit.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER);

    submit.addClickListener(e->this.handleSubmit());

    goodScan = new Audio(null, new ThemeResource( "sounds/good-scan.mp3"));
    goodScan.setAutoplay(false);
    goodScan.setShowControls(false);

    badScan = new Audio(null, new ThemeResource( "sounds/bad-scan.mp3"));
    badScan.setAutoplay(false);
    badScan.setShowControls(false);

    addComponents( goodScan, badScan );
```

Note that I turned auto-play and controls off, so it won't show up on the screen.  Actually, at least in my case, the "setShowContrtols(false)" is what hides things, it seems.  Later, in my submit method, I have this ( "..." for unrelated code ):

```
    private void submit() { 
        try {       
...
            barcode.setValue(null);
            barcode.focus();
            goodScan.play();
        } catch (WMSException e) {
...
            Notification.show("Consumption Scan Error", message, Type.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            barcode.focus();
            badScan.play();
        }
...
    }
```

The above works on desktops, but does not work consistently ( if at all ) on Android and iOS devices.  I have not dug back into this since the original post because I have had no ideas myself, and people I have asked did not have anything new to offer.

All that said, the above code should work for Vaadin 8 ( knock on wood ), which might help you, Basil.

Comment: I too would like to play just a short "beep" to get user's attention in my Vaadin 8 app. Example: when entering a new password twice does not match.

Comment: I can get "beeps" to work on desktops, just not on mobile devices, at least with Vaadin 7.  I will add a code/pseudo code snippet to my original post.  It might help you, and might help others answer my question.

Comment: Am implementing on push notification section to notify user they have received a message. Very insightful!